# How to run YCSB against remote HBase

Tags: hbase, ycsb

I have a 1+2 cluster running Hadoop-2.5.2 and HBase-1.2.3 (both fully distributed) running with no problems at all(verified). I downloaded and built the most recent version of YCSB (0.13.0) to run it against HBase! I also made the "**usertable**" table with "**family**" column.

1. [1st case]I run YCSB from the Hadoop-HBase-master-VM with this command: `./bin/ycsb load hbase10 -P workloads/workloada -p columnfamily=family` and everything works fine.
2. But what I want, [2nd case] is to have another VM which runs exclusively YCSB (a ycsb-client-VM). But, when I try to run YCSB from another VM I can't manage to run the afforementioned command succesfully. I tried with a lot of ways (I have already created /conf dir inside hbase10-binding and stored hbase-site.xml in it), and each time a get a different error which will make the post huge if I mention all of them here.

Has anyone run YCSB against HBase from a different server than HBase is running? (I describe it as "2nd case", above)

Is there any tutorial on how to run YCSB from dedicated ycsb-client-vm? (Of course I have read everything from YCSB-github).

*Please, don't give me advices on how to run YCSB in the same VM that HBase(master) is running!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luckily enough, I managed to receive an answer by posting the same question as an issue to the official YCSB-github-repo:
https://github.com/brianfrankcooper/YCSB/issues/886